# How to control each card using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to use react with material-ui

There are two cards,

When I click the expand button, both of them are open at the same time

How to open only one card in one click ?

I know is because when it setExpanded, all of the item will be set,
I have try add the key but it still don't work.

Here is the code I tested.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kwexep?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: You either need to store an array of booleans, one for each card, indicating whether that card itself is open. Or another way would be to create a card component and have a state inside there, so each card has its own internal state controlling the open-ness of itself (this is assuming you don't need to know about whether a card is expanded or not in the parent)

Comment: @Jayce444 thank you !  I'll try second solution.

Answer (score 3):

a simple solution is to store the index value of the expanded card and then pass the `expanded` prop based on the index value stored in the expanded state.

```
export default function App() {
  let data=[{
      id:1,
      title:"2"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title:"3"
    }]
    
const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = (index) => {
    expanded === index ? setExpanded(null) : setExpanded(index)
  };

  return (
    data.map((i,index)=>(
    <Card className={classes.root} >
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded ===index,
          })}
          onClick={()=>handleExpandClick(index)}
          aria-expanded={expanded === index}
          aria-label="show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse in={expanded===index} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>     </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            {i.title}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>

    ))
  );
}
```

Here is the working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yyycsr?file=src%2FApp.js